# Unable to create TAGVIEW in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am having a collection view. I want to create cells of collection view as TAGS. I Have written but it does not calculate the width & also left,irght margin among cells. Please tell me how can I improve it ?

```
extension StoreItemCell:UICollectionViewDelegate {
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let width = CGSize(
        return self.sizingCell!.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    }        
}



 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self.tagsCollectionView.delegate = self
        self.tagsCollectionView.dataSource = self
        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: Titles.CellIdentifier.TagCell, bundle: nil)
        self.tagsCollectionView.register(cellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Titles.CellIdentifier.TagCell)
        self.tagsCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.sizingCell = (cellNib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil) as NSArray).firstObject as! TagCell?
        self.flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)
        self.flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 15
    }
```

Please tell me how can I improve it. I have attached the screenshot for my design.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this one

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let Labell : UILabel = UILabel()

        Labell.text =   self.TagsArray[indexPath.item] as? String
        let labelTextWidth =   Labell.intrinsicContentSize.width
        return CGSize(width: labelTextWidth + 10, height: 30)


    }
```

create UILabel in

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
}
```

Comment: I don't think creating label like this is good idea because I will create so many label object in memory. I can have upto 10 tags for each cel if there 20 cells so 200 objects will be created just for one screen which may cause memory issue

Comment: @DhirajKumar . I am saying to create one label use it many times

Comment: But label will be created as many times as cellforitem is called

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be in your parent class, not in cell class,

```
extension YourViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate { 
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

            return //YourCellSize here
    }
  }
```

You have to use that delegate method in your parent class. Not in Cell Class.